# flutter place widget on bottom of screen in expanded

Tags: flutter

like the title says is there a way to place a widget on bottom of screen in expanded

```
Expanded -> SingleChildScrollView() -> column(children: [ -> Container() -> ElevatedButton() ])
```

i want the ElevatedButton to be placed on the bottom of screen also i don't want to place it away of the Expanded widget, is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
     children: [
       Container(),
       //use Spacer(),
       Spacer(),
       ElevatedButton()
     ],
     
   ),
)
```

try use spacer inside column

Comment: it gave me an error  RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f6c28 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
 but when i removed SingleChildScrollView it woked really fine but i need to keep the SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - APPBAR_SIZE,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(child: CHILD),
          ElevatedButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

UPDATE:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - APPBAR_SIZE - ElevatedButtonHeight,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(child: CHILD),
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: now it's not scrolling

Comment: Check my update